# Is there any way to set the ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable from within Visual Studio in the project/solution properties?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, android-ndk, environment-variables

I'm setting up build and release process for a project that does some Windows and Android development through Visual Studio 2013 (though some projects still have to have 2012 configs). I'd like for the developers to be able to stay within Visual Studio and not have to jump out to System Properties to change their environment variables in order to test another version of the NDK/SDK.

In the property sheets there's a setting that allows you to define a User Macro and expose it as an environment variable. I've followed the instructions from here ([Visual Studio Property Pages Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919413/visual-studio-property-pages-environment-variables)) however it doesn't appear to be working (at least not for doing Android stuff).

We tried setting the User Macro in the property sheet for the project as well as "Microsoft.cpp.Android.User" but still get the same error when building:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libstuff, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets(570,5): error : Could not find the Android NDK, check that your ANDROID_NDK_ROOT path is correct!
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets(570,5): error : It's currently: '<unset>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets(570,5): error : The NDK can be downloaded at this URL:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets(570,5): error : http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

We also tried a pre build event where we set the environment variable from the command line via a "set" with no luck.

Any thoughts on why this might not be working? Is the build order different when doing Android stuff that would cause the environment variables to be set and exposed after the Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets is called?

- UPDATE *

A small update on this.

We've been able to narrow this down to an issue with MSBuild and how it loads properties.

If you don't want to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT you can create a user macro to set those values.

Those are:
$(AndroidNdkDir) and $(AndroidsdkDir)

When MSBuild tries to execute any android build targets it loads two files.

The first is: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\vs-android.EnvVars.props

That is where AndroidNdkDir, AndroidSdkDir, and other android properties are set.

The second file depends on the android platform you're on. For example this is the file it's loading for us: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\PlatformToolsets\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8

In that file all the Gcc properties are set.

For some reason the AndroidNdkDir property that was set in the first file is not set. I don't see any settings in the Import tag in MSBuild that controls how/if other properties are inherited. Could this be some order of operation thing?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research is seems like the answer to this is that it cannot currently be done. I found this bullet point on the VS-Android plugin TODO list (https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/wiki/TODO_List)

> Ability to override environment variables for SDK/NDK/Ant/JDK on a
>   per-project basis in property sheets.